# No internet connection in PhoneGap app inside WP7 and WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, cordova-3

I have added below lines in my WMAppManifest.xml,

```
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
        <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
        <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
        <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
        <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
    </Capabilities>
```

Under config.xml I have added the below lines,

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="wp-package" value="NetworkStatus" />
</feature>
<feature name="Accelerometer">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Accelerometer" />
</feature>
<feature name="Compass">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Compass" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="wp-package" value="SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

Any help please?

Comment: According to the Phonegap doc (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) you need to add a line in your config.xml : <access origin="http://google.com" /> for example

Comment: I have added the below lines in config.xml but still same problem,           <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="http://google.com/*" />
    <access origin="http://maps.google.com/*" />

Comment: Any one can help with this please?

Comment: Try with this line : <access origin="*" /> (to access to all domains, including file:// protocol)